# How to get Multiple selected files using a sharpshell contextmenu?

Tags: c#, contextmenu, sharpshell

i am making an app that integrates in windows contextmenu,i am using sharpshell tutorials from CodeProject.com. is there any possible way of getting all information of all files that are selected because its giving information about only one file(selected and right click in the end).
Is this Possible.
if not how can i achieve my purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem with version 2.1. SelectedItemPaths from class SharpContextMenu should return the selected paths but there is a bug there: https://sharpshell.codeplex.com/workitem/1178, even if is marked as fixed.

Answer (score 0):

When using the Test Server (for debugging your code), SelectedItemPaths will hold only the last item selected and its count is 1.
When Server is installed and registered, all selected items will be held in SelectedItemPaths.